# MySQL query optimization using coalesce

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

Can someone explain to me why the second query is much faster than the first? (first one takes around 40 seconds, second one is less than 0.1)

```
SELECT releases.feature_code, releases.platform_id, version, release_date, general_available, uri, filesize, display_name, feature_name.full_name,
IF ((SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM release_exceptions WHERE 
releases.feature_code = release_exceptions.feature_code
 AND releases.platform_id = release_exceptions.platform_id 
 AND releases.version = release_exceptions.version) = 1), 
1, 0) as release_exceptions

FROM releases

LEFT OUTER JOIN platform USING(platform_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN feature_name USING(feature_code)

ORDER BY version DESC;
```

~~~

QUERY 2 ------------------

~~~

```
SELECT feature_code, version, release_date, general_available, platform_id, uri, filesize, display_name, feature_name.full_name, COALESCE(release_exceptions, 0) AS release_exceptions

FROM mus.releases

LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT DISTINCT feature_code, version, platform_id, 1 AS release_exceptions
FROM mus.release_exceptions
) release_exceptions
USING (feature_code, version, platform_id)

LEFT OUTER JOIN platform USING(platform_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN feature_name USING(feature_code)

;
```

It seems the way it generates the release_exceptions column is the big difference in speeds. My coworker wrote the second one, but is unable to explain why it's so much faster.

http://imgur.com/dXLuo6S,noRYV7v#0

First Image is the first query
(Note - feature_code, platform_id, and version were added as indexes after this posting, which results in the first one being slightly faster now)

Comment: Put an `EXPLAIN` before each query and look at the query plan.

Comment: I'm new to mySQL and don't really understand the diagrams. After indexing feature_code, platform_id, and version - the first one runs much faster. 

I'm not sure why the second one is faster without indexing.

Comment: As @ceejayoz said, put an `EXPLAIN` before the query and paste the results here. It will help us determine why one is faster than the other.

Comment: The second query does not have an `ORDER BY`.  That would explain a significant performance difference.

Comment: Okay I posted an imgur link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not the coalse that's causing the speed up. It's the removal of the sub query. The first runs a query per row

The second does a single sub query

Comment: I tried to upvote but it says I need a reputation of 15 or something. How do you accept the answer?

Comment: The green tick next to the answer :)